# How can I write this view efficiently?

Tags: django, view

I have a simple view in Django:

```
@render_to('episode_list.html')
def list_episodes(request, season):
    query = Episode.objects.filter(season=season)
    seasons = query[0].series.total_seasons    
    return  {'episodes': query,
             'season': season,
             'max_seasons':range(1,seasons + 1)}
```

I'm trying to build the navigation on my template dynamically and need 'max_seasons' to do it... Is there some better way to get this information, since it seems like this would make an extra database query.

The '.series' is referring to a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking it to be `query = Episode.objects.select_related('series').filter(season=season)` 
would follow the fk in the first DB hit, meaning you wouldn't need another, but it will pull/pre-fetch more Series results than the single one you (seem to) need if the queryset `query` contains more than one result (perhaps better to call it `episodes` for clarity?).

(But, even if it does pull more than you need, it is likely to still be faster)

Official docs are [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.select_related)